# FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined between I'm using react native and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

when I login I'm trying to get only messages for the logged in user, but I'm getting this error and I don't know what is the issue.

My Code:

```
const UserInbox = () => {

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const message = db.collection('feedback').where('recipient','==',userData.uid)
    const[recipient,setRecipient]=useState("")
    const[messageText,setMessageText]=useState("")
 

    {/*fetch only logged in user messages from database*/}
    const fetchData = async()=>{
        try {
            const list=[];
             await message
           //  .orderBy('submitTime','desc')
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot)=>{
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                    const {userId,recipient,messageText,} = doc.data()
                    list.push({
                        id:doc.id,
                        userId,
                        recipient,
                        messageText
                       // sendTime,
                        
                    })
                })
    
            })
            setUserData(list)
            if(loading){
                setLoading(false)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData()
    },[])

    function renderBody(){
        return(
            <ScrollView>
                 
            <FlatList 
                data={userData}
                numColumns={1}
                renderItem={({item})=>(
                <>
             <Swipeable 
                renderRightActions={()=>ListItemDelet(item.id)}> 
                <View>
                    <View>
                       <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                      <View>
                       <Text></Text>
                       <Text>{item.recipient}</Text>
                      </View>  

                      <TouchableOpacity  
                          onPress={()=>{
                             setRecipient(item.recipient),
                             setMessageText(item.messageText);
                           setModalVisible(true)}}>

                        <Text style={{
                            fontWeight:'600'
                        }}>View</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </View>                    
                    </View>
                </View>
                </Swipeable>
               </>
             )}
             />

             <View style={{
                position:'absolute',
                top:100,
                
             }}>
             <AppModal
                   modalVisible={modalVisible} 
                   setModalVisible = {setModalVisible} 
                   name={recipient}
                   messageText={messageText}
                   
               
                />    
             </View>
             
            
            </ScrollView>
           
        )
    }
```

so when I use .where('recipient','==',useData.uid) I get this error and when I delete it the code can correctly work. Howeve, My goal is to only retireve the messages from the database that belong to the logged in user. so each user login can only access his/her messages. any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You define `userData` as an array but try to access it as an object (`user.uid`).

`const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);`

`const message = db.collection('feedback').where('recipient','==',userData.uid)`

So then the issue is when you mount your component in the `useEffect` below, you run `fetchData()` which relies on `message` which is using `undefined` for the `recipient` comparison.

It seems like you meant to get the `uid` from somewhere else because inside `fetchData()` you're setting `userData` with a list of items - so you can't rely on `userData` on mount since it's empty / undefined.

Look into where the `uid` should actually be coming from.

**UPDATED ANSWER

In a `Firebase Function`, in order to make sure the user who called the function is authenticated (logged-in), use the `context` parameter from the `onCall` type function:

```
.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.auth == undefined) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition',
      'The user must be authenticated.',
    );
  }
  const uid = context?.auth?.uid as string;
  
  ...

  // Do your uid-based queries here.
  const message = db.collection('feedback').where('recipient','==', uid)

  ...

});
```

Let me know if that does not help!

Comment: the uid can be coming from the same document 'feedback' or from 'users' document  because when admin send feedback message to the users via this code:                                                                                     `const sendMessage = async()=>{

        setLoader(true)

        db.collection('feedback').add({
             userId:auth.currentUser?.uid,
              recipient:recipient,
             messageText:messageText,
        })`                                              and then when the user login can only access the message that sent under his/ her uid.

Comment: Step through the logic and you will see the problem:

Step 1 -
`const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);`

Here, `userData` is an array `[]`. There is no such thing as `[].uid` - this is `undefined`.

Step 2 -
`const message = db.collection('feedback').where('recipient','==',userData.uid)` ---

Here, `userData.uid` = `undefined`. Now your `Firestore` reference is checking for `undefined` `recipient`. Do you want this? ---

Step 3 - 
`const fetchData = async() => await message.orderBy('submitTime','desc')...`

Here `message` is a reference to your `undefined` `[].uid`.

Comment: thank you so much for your great explanation.? so what do you suggest me the value to put in `const [userData, setUserData = useState([])`

Comment: No problem. I understand why you have `userData` as an array - because you are setting a list of items below `setUserData(list)`.

The problem is the `fetchData` function relies on a variable it's setting - and you are calling the `uid` incorrectly. The `userData.uid` never exists, because that's an array. Perhaps `userData[0].uid` or `userData[1].uid` exist, but `userData.uid` cannot.

I would figure out why you use `userData.uid` inside this query reference --- `.where('recipient','==',userData.uid)` <--- `userData.uid` is `undefined`

For starters, remove that .where() clause entirely

Comment: Thank you again, I'm really stuck with this issue for days after hundreds tries . so now when I remove the `.where('recipient','==',userData.uid)` I can get all message for all user but I would only get for the logged in user. your help is unforgotten if you could be patient to figure it out and thank you so much

Comment: It sounds like you are using a Firebase Function and need to use the authenticated user's UID! I will update the answer now.

Comment: Yes Exactly, I'm using firebase and react native . don't know how to thank you for real? I really appreciate your great help and effort.

Comment: I'm glad that helped! If you feel the problem is resolved you can resolve / mark it with a green checkmark :) Cheers!

Comment: No, I'm still stuck waiting for your update answer sir.

Comment: Check the updated answer - it shows how to access the authenticated user's UID in a Firebase Function. ;)

Comment: sure I'm checking rigth now

Comment: it is Not helping sir, and this code is in typescript between I'm using javascript

Comment: I think the original question is answered - `userData.uid` is `undefined`. Not enough context otherwise sorry, good luck.